# Correct relational operator/function for comparison of vec3 values?

Tags: opengl, compare, glsl

I'm trying to check if vec3 values have the same components.

```
int same = 0;

vec3 v1 = vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
vec3 v2 = vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

if (v1 == v2) // <- this part
{
    same = 1;
}
```

Is == the correct relational operator for vec3 type?

If not, what can I use (operators and functions are also welcome) to compare vec3 values?

Comment: Maybe [`equal()` *(from the book I just try to read)*](https://thebookofshaders.com/glossary/?search=equal)

Comment: `equal` will perform a component wise comparison and return a boolean vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [GLSL 4.5 Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.50.pdf), Section 5.9 states:

> The equality operators equal (==), and not equal (!=) operate on all types [...]. They result in a scalar Boolean. [...] For vectors, matrices, structures, and arrays,
>   all components, members, or elements of one operand must equal the corresponding components,
>   members, or elements in the other operand for the operands to be considered equal.

To answer your question: Yes, the `==` operator compares weather two vectors have the same value in all components.

Comment: Don't forget float arithmetic issues about numerical imprecisions. Numbers such `1.0` or `0.0` will work well, `0.1` will not.

Comment: Thank you, I was a bit confused because my header wouldn't recognize the boolean function equal(). Just found out that == or != would be perfect.